# Add class to element that doesn't have class - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the `table` below only one `td` has class, another doesn't have class like:

```
<table id="bow-me">
  <tr class="row-me">
    <td class="show-me">Pet is Great</td>
    <td>Pete is Greate</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried something like:

```
if(!$("#bow-me tr td").hasClass("show-me")) {
  $(this).addClass("know-me");
}
```

But this doesn't add the `class` ***know-me*** in my second `td` here.

I have attached the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hGkk9/)

If I want to add Class to the second `td` only then how do I do?

Comment: just for clarity. an if block will not define 'this'.

Comment: do you mean in `if()` block if I define `$('#id')` then I cannot do `$(this)` in **jQuery**? `this` in JavaScript is really confusing

Comment: `if()` is just a condition and does not define the this keyword. you can use `$(this)` in an `if()` block but it will not reference the conditional value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try attribute selector and [`:not()`](http://jsfiddle.net/BT3gX/) to get the `<td>` without any class

```
$('#bow-me tr td:not([class])').addClass('know-me');
```

Or if you want to specify which `<td>` like first or second, use `:eq()`

```
$('#bow-me tr td:eq(1)').addClass('know-me');
```

*Doc reference*

1. [:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
2. [Attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)
3. [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: **+1** Nicely selected with the first example, can't get any shorter than that!

Comment: Instead of knowing the `eq(n)` I think `:not()` is perfect for most solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** selector:

```
$('#bow-me tr.row-me td:eq(1)').addClass('know-me');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hGkk9/1/)**

or **[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)**

```
$('#bow-me tr.row-me td').eq(1).addClass('know-me');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hGkk9/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

the reason your code doesn't work is because

1. There are multiple `td`'s found with your selector

   `$("#bow-me tr td")`
2. You can't use the `$(this)` as a selector inside your if conditional statement. it has no valid reference as is.

Solution: you can cycle through the matched elements via `each()` function and then set up your conditional to check each one of the elements found - `$(this)` would work in this case

```
$("#bow-me tr td").each(function() {
  if(! $(this).hasClass("show-me")) {
    $(this).addClass("know-me");
  }
});
```

check out the [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hGkk9/3/)

I gave this answer as an explaination as to why your approach does not work.
I prefer Anton's approach that uses the `:not()` pseudo selector.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it is informative, I learned something new in JavaScript today.